# SQL efficient way to match ANY in a large table

Tags: sql

I am joining a small table and a very large table and want to return a distinct item if ANY items match. The table is so large that it takes hours for something that I think should take seconds.

The problem is that I am "iterating" over every single entry in the second table. I want to be able to "break" once a condition is met and return that value instead of continuing over every single account.

In the code below, I am finding every single row for each `name` that I am joining, even though I am only returning the `DISTINCT example.name` and don't care about every row. How can I return `DISTINCT.name` after finding the first instance of `new_ex.data = ...` after performing the `INNER JOIN`?

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT example.name
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ex.user AS name
    FROM exampleTable ex
    WHERE ex.timestamp >= '2022-01-01'
    AND ex.group = 'test'
    AND new_ex.data = '123'
) AS example_users
INNER JOIN exampleTable new_ex on example_users.name = new_ex.user
AND new_ex.timestamp >= '2022-01-01'
AND (
    OR new_ex.data = 'abc'
    OR new_ex.data = 'def'
    OR new_ex.data = 'ghi'
    -- ~10 more of these OR statements
)
```

Comment: *I want to be able to "break" once a condition is met* that's almost the dictionary definition of an `exists()` clause

Comment: Can you `exists()` after a join?

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [(minimal) complete example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data. For this particular question, it's important to be able to see what indices are defined on the tables. See the help center for more on [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and many other helpful topics.

Comment: The sample query doesn't match the description, as the sample involves only a single table, while the description mentions 2 different tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the data it's hard to be sure this can't be simplified further, but I think you can at least boil this down to

```
select distinct ex.user as name
from exampleTable ex
where ex.timestamp >= '2022-01-01'
and ex.group = 'test'
AND new_ex.data = '123'
and exists (
    select 1
    from exampleTable new_ex 
    where new_ex.user=ex.name
        and new_ex.data = '123'
        and new_ex.timestamp >= '2022-01-01'
        and new_ex.data in ('abc','def','ghi'...)
)
```

Comment: I see. So there is no need for a `join`?

Comment: Not in the query you have as presented since you are only joining to assert a correlation, you are not retrieveing any additional columns from the joined table whether a self-join or otherwise.

Comment: This appears to be the trick. Thank you. I will implement this now and upvote you when I have enough reputation.

Comment: performance-wise, does this pull the same table twice, since there are two `from` statements with the same table name?

Comment: This will involve either a semi-join or hash join to the same table, you would need to review the execution plan; it will be efficient with the correct indexes

Answer (score 0):

Use below query, using multiple OR will cause performance issue. Instead use IN.

```
select DISTINCT ex.user from exampleTable ex
INNER JOIN exampleTable new_ex on example_users.user = new_ex.user
where ex.timestamp >= '2022-01-01'
AND ex.group = 'test'
AND new_ex.timestamp >= '2022-01-01'
AND new_ex.data in ('abc', 'def', 'ghi'); -- include all your values
```

You can also use below query,

```
select DISTINCT ex.user from exampleTable ex
INNER JOIN (select distinct user, timestamp, data from exampleTable) new_ex on example_users.user = new_ex.user
where ex.timestamp >= '2022-01-01'
AND ex.group = 'test'
AND new_ex.timestamp >= '2022-01-01'
AND new_ex.data in ('abc', 'def', 'ghi'); -- include all your values
```

Comment: Using an OR criteria over multiple columns could be a performance issue, but on the same column using OR or In() will share the same plan